# Deploying Android Hello world on DELL XCD35

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have created a successfully hello world program with an image in it. and here is how it looks on windows 7

[image: android-hello-world]

I have now connected to my DELL XCD to the computer, ensured that "USB Debugging" is ticked and also made sure that "Settings > Applications and enable Unknown sources" is ticked

I have followed all the steps given here - [in android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

But the following steps fail:

> You can verify that your device is connected by executing adb devices
>   from your SDK platform-tools/ directory. If connected, you'll see the
>   device name listed as a "device."

Here no device is displayed in command prompt.

> If using Eclipse, run or debug your application as usual. You will be
>   presented with a Device Chooser dialog that lists the available
>   emulator(s) and connected device(s). Select the device upon which you
>   want to install and run the application.

And this doesn't happen

I have the following packages installed currently
[image: android-eclipse-installed-packages]

So how to deploy my simple hello world program on my phone now?

Comment: You will probably need USB driver for you phone. I had experienced with sony xperia phone before. After i installed driver from sony websites, i was able to use my phone to debug my apps.

Comment: You may need the USB driver for your phone.In eclipse , yo

Comment: oh yes, you guys are right, but problem was that the USB driver is NOT available in the official website, so had to search a bit more, posted it in answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After exhaustive search i found out that the USB driver required for
>   my DELL XCD35 was available in the form of a .exe file on my mobile's
>   original Micro SD memory card. The shocker was that there was no
>   direct download available from DELL's website for the same. So if you
>   loose this file, or have exchanged the Micro SD card for a better
>   version then you are in trouble as you wont get it from DELL also.

So folks, i have uploaded the same file  for those who want it. - [Dell Phone Android USB Connector Device Driver](http://ajitah.com/others/DellPhone%20for%20android.exe)

**PS:** I spent so much time on this silly matter that i had to let others know of this and [wrote an article](http://ajitah.com/blog/?p=1007) for the same, so that others don't make the same mistake lol.